# How to get a list of IP connected in same network (subnet) using Java

Tags: java, networking

How do I get list of IP addresses for devices connected to my same subnet using Java?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "IPs connected in LAN"?

Comment: all the posts you have given are little bit time consuming and takes 8 minutes to search 50 PCS connected to the Lan, i want the fastest way to get Ip addresses connected to the Lan
so that i can display it on the JCOMBOBOX
please anybody gives me the fastest way,

Answer (score 54, accepted):

this should work when the hosts on your network react to ICMP packages (ping) (>JDK 5):

```
public void checkHosts(String subnet){
   int timeout=1000;
   for (int i=1;i<255;i++){
       String host=subnet + "." + i;
       if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
           System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
       }
   }
}
```

invoke the method for a subnet (192.168.0.1-254) like this:

```
checkHosts("192.168.0");
```

didnt test it but should work kinda like this. Obviously this only checks the 254 hosts in the last byte of the ip address...

check:

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29
http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-do-icmp-ping-in-java-jdk-15-and-above/

hope that helped

Comment: Good solution provided 'LAN' = 'class D IP subnet'.

Comment: Thanks for providing explanation.

Comment: The OS must surely have this information already, is there some way to retrieve it as this implementation could take a while...

Comment: Great and Elegant solution I was looking for.

Comment: how fast is this process takes time?

Comment: @fasseg Any idea how to get the MAC address for each reachable device?

Comment: Im thinking this might be slow, is there a faster method?

Comment: you may reduce the value of timeOut to be 300, this will reduce proccess time and still works for local network.

Answer (score 6):

To list the hosts connected in a LAN you will need to ping all the available IP addresses on the subnet. But a ping message could be restricted by firewall thus safer way could be open a socket to each IP address in the LAN's IP address range.

Comment: socket? to which port? and how to be so sure that firewall does not block it?

Comment: +1 for providing basic information to ping all ip's in subnet.

Comment: And the LAN could be split across multiple subnets.

Comment: But this is too much slow to ping and get all local wifi addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 1.5 there is a ping-like method in java.net.InetAddress:
public boolean isReachable(int timeout). You could use that to iterate over all the IP Addresses in your subnet... [java-doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int))

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a list of all hosts connected to the network, I think the only way that is guaranteed to work is to step through a list of IP addresses and ping them all.

That said, if you're looking for something more specific, there may be something you can look up (e.g. RMI's registry (`LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port).list()`).

Also, if you just want all the IP addresses that a given host has, have a look at `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`.

Comment: Nope. LocateRegistry.getRegistry doesn't do any communications whatsoever. It just constructs a Registry stub.

Comment: Calling list() on it should, though. Anyway, it's a bit moot - I'm forgetting that by default RMI only allows objects to register with local registries, so you'd still need to check for a registry on every host. You'd need to use something like Bonjour to do service discovery - which was my point.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the other answer. Its pretty well. But its quite slow as compared to a real situation and should not be used in such a senario.

Here is what i am talking about.

When i use the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345981/14911094

**Code:**

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception{
        long initialT = System.currentTimeMillis();
        checkHosts("192.168.0");
        long finalT = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Scan Completed taking " + (finalT - initialT) + " miliseconds approximately!");
    }
    
    public static void checkHosts(String subnet) throws Exception{
   int timeout=1000;
   for (int i=1;i<255;i++){
       String host=subnet + "." + i;
       if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
           System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
       }
   }
}
}
```

**The Output:**

```
sudo java Main
[sudo] password for jaysmito: 
192.168.0.1 is reachable
192.168.0.2 is reachable
192.168.0.3 is reachable
192.168.0.4 is reachable
192.168.0.10 is reachable
Scan Completed taking 250151 miliseconds approximately!
```

This is pretty slow but i tried to make a better version using this concept:

**Code:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class AddressFinderLevel4 extends Thread{
  private String addmask;
  private Stack<String> stack;
  private int start, end;

  public AddressFinderLevel4(String addmask, Stack stack, int start, int end){
    this.addmask = addmask;
    this.stack = stack;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    try{
        int timeout=1000;
      for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
        String host=addmask + "." + i;
            if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
                stack.push(host);
            }
      }
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
  }
}

class AddressFinderLevel3 extends Thread{
  private String addmask;
  private Stack<String> stack;
  private int start, end;
  private int packSize;

  public AddressFinderLevel3(String addmask, Stack stack, int packSize, int start, int end){
    this.addmask = addmask;
    this.stack = stack;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.packSize = packSize;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    try{
      for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
        int j = 1;
        String host =  addmask + "." + i;
        while(j<=255){
          AddressFinderLevel4 addressFinderLevel4 = new AddressFinderLevel4(host, stack, j, j+packSize+5);
          addressFinderLevel4.start();
          j = j + packSize;
        }
      }
    }catch(Exception ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("Starting search!");
      Stack data = find();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println("Data found in 1000 miliseconds");
      data.forEach(System.out::println);
      Thread.sleep(10000);
      System.out.println("Data found in 10000 miliseconds");
      data.forEach(System.out::println);
      Thread.sleep(25000);
      System.out.println("Data found in 25000 miliseconds");
      data.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static Stack find(){
      Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
      AddressFinderLevel3 finder = new AddressFinderLevel3("192.168", stack, 10, 0, 255);
      finder.start();
      return stack;
    }
}
```

**The output:**

```
sudo java Main
Starting search!
Data found in 1000 miliseconds
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
Data found in 10000 miliseconds
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.99.152
192.168.0.10
192.168.102.227
192.168.99.161
Data found in 25000 miliseconds
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.99.152
192.168.0.10
192.168.102.227
192.168.99.161
```

As you can see this scans far more IPs in much much less time.

I had done it for all possible ips too but that takes too much memory and is not needed!

This is a faster solution thus should perform better!

Comment: What if I want to get Host Name and MAC Address ?

Answer (score 0):

Shows Active Addresses On LAN

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Enumeration nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while(nis.hasMoreElements())
        {
            NetworkInterface ni = (NetworkInterface) nis.nextElement();
            Enumeration ias = ni.getInetAddresses();
            while (ias.hasMoreElements())
            {
                InetAddress ia = (InetAddress) ias.nextElement();
                System.out.println(ia.getHostAddress());
            }

        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Output

```
127.0.0.1
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
172.128.1.102
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the question asked -- it will only return the addresses bound to the network devices, which are the addresses localhost has on various networks.

Comment: Yes, agree with @danielunderwood

Answer (score -1):

None of these were working for me as I had created the server and it didn't respond to these pings. So I created a mechanism that makes the server reply to a ping and used the brute force checking method for all addresses in the subnet.

PS: Writing this because someone creating their own server might need this.

Answer (score -3):

One of the problems here is that neither of the terms "LAN" and "connected" has a meaning in TCP/IP. The suggested technique of calling isReachable() on all the hosts in the class D subnet might work if your LAN corresponds precisely to a class-D subnet.

You might be better off looking at SAMBA, which can interrogate the LAN members via SMBs, so at least you'll be using a technique that has the same meaning for LAN that you do.