# possibility to see all IPs inside LAN

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, local

Hey, i'm trying to discover if it's possible to see all IPs of a LAN network so you can send files by using IP without entering the internet? :)

This is probably a stupid question for you guys but you'll do me a really big favor by explaining this! :D

Thanks!! :)

(ps: and yes it's only for educational use :D )

Comment: Given an IP and a netmask, you can easily figure out what's "inside" and "outside" the network.

Answer (score 1):

If this is indeed for Java as you've tagged the question. Then a nice solution has been posted here: [How to get a list of IP connected in same network (subnet) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345857/how-to-get-list-of-ip-connected-in-lan-using-java)

Something like this: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html explains a very simple client-server architecture, transferring a file via a socket in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a LAN in TCP/IP. There are subnets, and they can be easily enumerated via arithmetic, given the subnet mask.