# Java api to find network nodes

Tags: java

How to find all local network nodes in Java ?

Regards,

Chirag

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345857/how-to-get-list-of-ip-connected-in-lan-using-java)

```
public void checkHosts(String subnet){
   int timeout=1000;
   for (int i=1;i<254;i++){
       String host=subnet + "." + i;
       if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
           System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
       }
   }
}
```