# get ip addresses of all active routers in the network programmatically

Tags: c, linux, getaddrinfo

As for the part of my final year project I want to get a list of IP addresses of all the active routers in the network so that I can obtain it IPv6 status via `getaddrinfo` with the `AI_ADDRCONFIG` flag.

The current implementation of `getaddrinfo` works with 1 IP at a time and I need to change the IP from the source each time need to check another one. My aim is to create a list of IP address of active routers and parse the IP addresses to the `getaddrinfo` method.

I would be really grateful if you experts would point me to any references or provide any sample code segments to `get all the IP addresses of active routers` within a network.

PS: I found similar posts ([Find out IP of all active machines on network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978364/find-out-ip-of-all-active-machines-on-network)) on this topic in stackoverflow but these did not help me as they were for java and android and slightly off topic than mine ().

Comment: Although the question you linked is tagged [tag:java], the answers are fairly language agnostic.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thank you for the reply sir..I was trying to figure out but I am kinda new to this and thats one of the reasons I turned to you experts :)

Comment: The first answer does a ping only. But it makes a broadcast, so every machine on the LAN answers.

Comment: @OlafDietsche the first answer?

Comment: Sorry, it depends on your ordering of course. But there is only one answer using ping and the main point is anyway, that it uses a broadcast to detect all machines on the local net.

Comment: @OlafDietsche thank you very much for your support sir..i will check more on your suggestion :)