# Find IP and Mac Addresses of LAN Network without subnet

Tags: java, linux, sockets, arp, dd-wrt

I want to develop a software, my proper way is `JAVA`, It sounds simple, but has its own problems.
I have a Network in which there are some devices ( about 400 radios or more)
I do not know their IP.
I just know the first and second part of their `MAC` addresses.
I want to find out their IP and the whole `Mac` address of all.
They are in my network, and i have forgotten their `IP`, and also `MAC`.
I found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718748/get-all-ip-and-mac-address-in-lan) useful, but in this solution it is about remote connection to `nmap` and also you should known the range of IP.
Note that this not about `HACKING` Or better to say is not about `CRACKING` or something like this, I have thousands of Radio's and they have been reset and need to be `re-config`.
Actually i need their `MAC` to config more than IP.
There are other questions on the net, but they are about having subnet, I do not have `subnet` of the `LAN Network`.

Now i am looking for any solution with java or other programming languages, with `ARP` or `dd-wrt` something like that, any suggestion? or any solutions? Any sample? 
I appreciate this.
Thx all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of IP connected in same network (subnet) using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345857/how-to-get-a-list-of-ip-connected-in-same-network-subnet-using-java), [Find all IP addresses in local network](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32500182), [Get All IP and Mac Address in LAN](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35718748)

Comment: If i had sub net or IP, of course i could do that sir.
It is not duplicated, I could not find any solution on the net.

Comment: And also one of your link is in my question.

Comment: You should always know your IP and the IP range because your machine knows its IP address and network mask. If you want to discover devices on another LAN, then you will have to provide the other network. How do you expect a program to guess what network you want to discover? If you visit the cited dups, you will likely find your answer (and learn none of them are this question).

Answer (score 0):

If this is your network, inspect ARP tables form network devices. You get all MAC addresses and corresponding IPs. Use SNMP protocol and corresponding libs to get this data form your Java code.

To test this approach use snmpwalk utility.

Comment: Thx sir, Do you have any link? or any sample?
Thx srir

Comment: From connected device, run "route -n" and look for Gateway IP. To look what is inside SNMP use Windows tool: https://www.sysaid.com/Sysforums/posts/list/2287.page OR Linux tool: https://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpwalk. After you see necessary data from SNMP, you can use libs like this http://www.snmp4j.org to process it in code.