# How to discover host in a WiFi network in Android (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, networking

I'm developing an Android application, I have to discover each hosts in a WiFi network, I have implemented a function that "ping" all IP  address between 1 and 255 of a certain network.

This solution it work perfectly, but there is a problem, the execution time.. Every time that i start my application I wait about 256 second, it too long, i can't wait this time.

This is my source code (i found this code on Stack, i modified the code to work in my condition):

```
public class ScanNetwork {

    ArrayList < String > hosts;

    int i;
    boolean finish = false;
    public ArrayList < String > ScanNetwork(String ipAddress) {

        hosts = new ArrayList < String > ();
        final String subnet = ipAddress.substring(0, ipAddress.lastIndexOf("."));

        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            String currentHost = subnet + "." + i;
            Process p1 = null;
            int returnVal = 0;
            try {
                p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -w 50 -c 1 " + currentHost);
                returnVal = p1.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Log: " + e.toString());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Log: " + e.toString());
            }

            boolean reachable = (returnVal == 0);
            if (reachable) {

                if (!hosts.contains(currentHost)) {
                    hosts.add(currentHost);
                    System.out.println(currentHost);

                }
            }
        }
        return hosts;
    }
}
```

This source code is perfect but the execution time is excessive, there are other way to obtain all the host in the network ?

How i can solve this problem ?

Comment: refer this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277912/how-to-scan-ip-in-android/36278723#36278723). It might be helps you. just increase timeout from 5 to 20. It will gives you all `IP` in local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that you are doing all the pings sequentially - the loop is spending most of its time waiting for replies.  Try starting up a few AsyncTasks, each of which has an assigned range of addresses to search, and let them work in parallel.

Note that for a typical 192.168.1.x network, ".0" (all 0 bits) ".255" (all 1 bits) will not correspond to a host and doesn't need checking.

Also don't forget that not everybody responds to a ping (this is more likely in a corporate network, less so at home)

Comment: My idea was the implementation of multithreading, different thread would take care of managing a number of " scans " , similar to your solution. But unfortunately I can not figure out how to manage the creation and termination of automatic thread for this solution

Comment: AsyncTask will handle the creation and termination of the thread, as well as passing information to/from the task.  For example, you can pass in the range of addresses for this thread to check, and use onProgressUpdate() or onPostExecute() to send the results back to the UI thread