# how to get list of all connected devices to the one router programmatically in android?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app in which I want to shows list of `all devices` which are connected to `one router` using `wifip2p` same like in `xender`. I don't know how to do this because I am new in Android programming.

[image]

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345857/how-to-get-a-list-of-ip-connected-in-same-network-subnet-using-java

Comment: @LuísGonçalves I want devices connected with wifi not with LAN

Comment: Have you looked into possible available API's of the router's brand?

Answer (score 1):

This [GitHub](https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery) Repo called **Android Network Discovery** might help you to get list of all contected devices.